# Animate SwiftUI list containing buttons

Tags: animation, button, swiftui, swiftui-animation

In SwiftUI, if I add a Button to a List, the List no longer animates when the collection changes. How can I make it animate?

Here's a reproduction. In the code's current form, animation works when the list is shuffled. However, if I replace `Text` with `Button`, the list no longer animates when I tap Shuffle.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(fruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                Text(fruit)
                // Button(fruit) {} // Uncomment this line and comment the line above to reproduce the problem.
            }
            .toolbar {
                Button("Shuffle") {
                    withAnimation { fruits = fruits.shuffled() }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default button style within a List has some built-in behaviors that affect animations and interaction.

You should add the modifier .buttonStyle(.plain) to fix it

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        List {
            ForEach(fruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Text(fruit)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                }
                .buttonStyle(.plain)
            }
          
        }
        
        .toolbar {
            Button("Shuffle") {
                withAnimation {
                    fruits.shuffle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


}
```